# How can we read NetworkType() of both sim cards individually on a dual sim device?

Tags: android, network-programming, gsm, cellular-network

```
telephonyManager.NetworkType();

above android code only able to get Networktype() of active sim card.
```

is there any method or command to read NetworkType() of both sim cards individually on a dual sim device. I search lot in internet and did not found any relevant method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.